# How to use newlib instead of glibc

Tags: gcc, cygwin, glibc, configure, newlib

I want to use newlib instead of glibc because I work on cygwin. The github project I want to use uses glibc as default, because I'm on cygwin I cant use glibc, so I want to use newlib but I don't know how.

Comment: what have you tried, where is the issue ? `newlib` is the default `libc` of cygwin, the gcc compiler automatically links against it.

Comment: When I try to use ./configure on the repo, it gives me this `configure: error: Could not use standard C library` error

Comment: That's an issue specific to the project you are building. Maybe it doesn't support anything other than glibc (yet). There is no magic switch you can flip to add support. You (or project maintainers) need ro find out why this message is printed and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a solution, as we have no clue of your project, but more a general recipe of what need to be done as already mentioned by another comment.

Check on config.log more details on

```
configure: error: Could not use standard C library
```

If it is a generic `Glibc` test you can remove/change in a warning/comment the test in
configure.ac and than run `autoreconf` to rebuild `configure`

https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.70/html_node/autoreconf-Invocation.html

After that you run again `configure` and than chase and analyze any further error during the configure, build and test phases.

If it is not a generic glib test, but if it is a proper test of a C functionality you need to analyze what is the expected behavior and if `Newlib` can provide it in a alternate way.